# Reference one foreign key to multiple primary keys in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have three tables in my database.

1. **MedicalTest** [MedicalTestID PK]
2. **SportTest** [SportTestID PK]
3. **GeneralNeeds** [GeneralNeedsID PK]

[image]

Inside `GeneralNeeds` there is `ProcessID` which needs to keep `MedicalTestID` and `SportTestID` GUID.

As soon as I insert an existing GUID from either tables I get "Conflict" error message which I believe it means the given GUID doesn't exist in the other table.

For example: If I insert the GUID from `MedicalTest` then it will tell me that the `SportTest` doesn't have the given GUID.

[image]

Is it possible to reference multiple keys to one column?

[image]

Comment: `GUID`?Can it be primary key?

Comment: Can you give the full error message? Also, which table are you inserting into when you get the message?

Comment: You'd have to remove the foreign key relationship. It's a bad idea to do this though and goes against how you're supposed to use foreign keys.

Comment: @dman2306 I agree with you. What if I turn off the "enforce foreign key constraint"?

Comment: Foreign key constraints keep you from inserting bad data. Working with them can be difficult, but it's not nearly as difficult as querying bad data.

Comment: Can you also post the SQL for your foreign key constraint(s)? What you're trying to do is common; perhaps there's a simple mistake in the constraint definition(s)?

Comment: That's exactly what I said you should NOT do. It's very bad database design. Why not have two separate columns?

Comment: @dman2306 The only reason I can't add two columns is simply because I have 10 other tables which their ID needs to be saved in ProcessID. Is it still a good idea to create 10 columns?

Comment: So you have 10 types of "tests"?

Comment: Kevin, the error message is a standard "foreign key value doesn't exist". It's saying that the value you inserted into (presumably) `GeneralNeeds.ProcessID` doesn't exist in `SportTest.SportTestID`.

Comment: @dman2306 Exactly and each have their own needs and that GeneralNeeds is acting as log to keep track of all the needs for different tests.

Comment: @EdGibbs exactly, because each time I insert any key from any of those tables SQL checks each of the ID and it's very natural that the same ID won't be available in other tables.

Comment: The design I'd recommend here is a table/sub-table solution. What that means is, introduce a 4th table, `Test`. `Test` can be a very simple table, it can have just an ID and maybe a `Type` that identifies it as Medical, Sports, etc. In your `MedicalTest` table you can copy the primary key from `Test` to say the `MedicalTest`. Then you make your foreign key from `Test` to `GeneralNeeds` rather than one of the sub tables.

Comment: @EdGibbs in that error, I was inserting the value from MedicalTest but SQL checked the other table (SportTest) and said, Hey, you can't do this because that ID doesn't exist there.

Comment: @dman2306 your suggestion sounds very interesting, can you please expand it and make it little-bit more clear and then post it below?

Comment: Got it. The way your tables are set up, a General Needs row must have a related Medical Test *and* a related Sports Test, both with the same ID. Since that's not your intention, I'd recommend pursuing the recommendation from @dman2306; it'll work.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell Give me 5 mins I'm putting together a database diagram

Comment: @dman2306 no problem, please take your time. Thank you

Comment: @EdGibbs I updated my post again with a new picture which simply may describe what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I was taking the data diagram too literally - but then again so does SQL Server :) I think @dman2306 will take care of your question nicely here. Good luck!

Comment: @EdGibbs Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design I'd recommend here is a table/sub-table solution. What that means is, introduce a 4th table, `Test`. The `Test` table just serves as a table that links all the different test types together. If you're familiar with Object Oriented Programming, think of it as a base type. So essentially, your `ProcessID` points to `Test` which then points to one of the specific test types (SportsTest, MedicalTest, WhateverTest). If you like, you could also include a `Type` in the `Test` table to help you know which type of test it is. There is a key thing here: In the `MedicalTest` and `SportsTest` table, the primary key (say `MedicalTestID`) is also a foreign key that points to the `TestID` in `Test`. In this way you can use a single column in your `GeneralNeeds` because the reference is to a single table type, `Test`. Since `Test` and the corresponding `MedicalTest` or `SportsTest` would have the same primary key, you can easily do the joins you need to do the query.

Here is a sample diagram illustrating it:[image: DB Diagram]

Simple example:
Say you have a `MedicalTest` with ID of 1 (let's forget GUIDs for a minute to make it easier to read)
Then you'd also have a record in `Test` with an ID of 1.
Then the `ProcessID` of 1 really points to the `Test` record which you could then join to the `MedicalTest` record.

If you're still confused let me know and I'll try to add a bit more detail but hopefully this gets you going in a direction that works.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing all this. So what I understand is that the `Test` table with its TestID is going to be connected to my various tests and then same TestID will be connected to ProcessID, correct?

Comment: Exactly! The one catch is you need to be careful that whenever you create a `Test` you also create a record in the corresponding other test table for the specific type. Same thing on a delete. For delete, you could consider turning on `CASCADE DELETE` and always delete from `Test` and let SQL Server delete the  sub-type automatically.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about that situation. I will keep in mind and update my key actions.

Comment: I will update my structure and then I will keep you posted on the progress. Thank you so much for your speedy response.

Comment: Hello again, I think I still need your help. I updated my structure according to your diagram and I still get the same error message. Let me add something: `MedicalTest` and `SportTest` IDs are not the same, they have their own GUID so when I add something in `Test` it says that GUID doesn't exist in the other table. Because it checks the both tables.

Comment: That's the problem. The key in `Test` must match the value in the other test tables.

Comment: The problem is that those 10 tests won't happen at the same time and not all the members need to go through those tests. Basically I want a container where many IDs can be stored. Each test will have its own corresponding needs if needed.

Comment: The `GeneralNeeds` is actually a Log container where many different IDs can be stored. For example I would do this way: `Select GeneralNeeds.Item from GeneralNeeds where ProcessID = MedicalTestID` so basically it will retrieve all the needs for that specific Medical test.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you show your error? Does the GUIs in Test match MedicalTest?