# Foreign key referring to 2 primary keys across 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

So i've got 3 relevant tables in my database : 
[image]

Now i need to create relationship between BAD.K02 and (K1.K02, SR.K02). What is the easiest way to do this? 
I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429732/reference-one-foreign-key-to-multiple-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2014) topic with almost same problem but i still can't make it work.

Can anybody help me or the only way to do this is to add 2nd foreign key to BAD table?

Comment: "Between" is unclear. Please edit your question to say very clearly (eg in a list): what table(s) have what column lists forming FKs referencing what column lists in what table(s)? A FK's subrow must also ppear in the referenced columns. The referenced column list must be declared PK *or* UNIQUE NOT NULL. Also: What happens when you try to define the FKs yourself? PS Please do not use images, use [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to create the two foreign key constraints. You can read more about it here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[K1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BAD_K1] FOREIGN KEY([K02])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BAD] ([K02])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[K1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BAD_K1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SR]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BAD_SR] FOREIGN KEY([K02])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BAD] ([K02])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SR] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BAD_SR]
GO
```

Comment: This looks really interesting but when i try to execute this i am getting errors:
`Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.BAD' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_BAD_K1'.`


`Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

I am using SQL Server 2005 maybe this is important.

Comment: @dejfit What do you find googling your error message & tags? PS Why can't you set BAD K02 to PK/UNIQUE? Why do you think you have a FK if the referenced columns aren't PK/UNIQUE?